# The Three.js model does not rotate, error unknown

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to rotate the model. However, I have no idea why my model is not rotating because there is no error shown on the developer tools. Therefore I can not identify what causes the error. I might be missing something in my code but I'm not sure where about. Please, if anyone has any solution on this, thank you for your advice.

```
let scene, camera, renderer, controls, car;

                function init() {
                    scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);

                    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
                    camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
                    camera.position.x = 40;
                    camera.position.y = 0;
                    camera.position.z = 40;

                    hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 0.001);
                    scene.add(hlight);

                    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x333333, 10);
                    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 0);
                    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                    scene.add(directionalLight);

                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
                    controls.addEventListener('change');


                    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
                    loader.load('./5/3D_model.gltf', function (gltf) {
                        car = gltf.scene.children[0];
                        car.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
                        scene.add(gltf.scene);
                        renderer.render(scene, camera);
                        animate();

                    });


                }
                function animate() {
                    if (car) car.rotation.y += 0.3;
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                }
                init();
                animate();
```

Comment: Does the car show up at all? Your camera might be pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Yes, the model shows up. The camera position is pointing to the object correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- You are setting an `undefined` event listener to the `change` event of `OrbitControls`. Please remove this line.
- You start the animation loop twice. Remove one call of `animate();`.
- Rotating the asset `0.3` per animation step is quite a lot. The model might rotate so fast that you don't see it. Use `0.01` for now.
- The intensity of the directional light is too high. Just use the default value for now. Besides, setting `castShadow` to `true` has no effect with your current scene setup.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I resolve these issues according to your suggestion but the object remains not rotating.

Comment: The please share the entire app as a GitHub repository or live example so it's possible to better debug the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is the model. I tried to change the 3D file to another and it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please upvote/accept the answer if it was useful to you.